# mysql ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: you have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I keep getting the following error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '

```
    Species_ID int,
    Genus varchar,
    Species varchar,
    Common_Name varchar,
    Indiv' at line 9
hbm248@i6[datasets]$
```

Here is the full SQL script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS paplants;

CREATE TABLE paplants (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Observation_ID int NOT NULL,
    Update_Datetime int NOT NULL,
    Site_ID int NOT NULL,
    Latitude decimal NOT NULL,
    Longitude decimal NOT NULL,
    Elevation_in_Meters int,
    `State` varchar,
    Species_ID int,
    Genus varchar,
    Species varchar,
    Common_Name varchar,
    Individual_ID int,
    Phenophase_ID int,
    Phenophase_Description varchar,
    Observation_Date date,
    Day_of_Year int,
    Phenophase_Status int,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    );

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "observation_data.csv"
    INTO TABLE paplants
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (ID, Observation_ID, Update_Datetime, Site_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Elevation_in_Meters, `State`, Species_ID, Genus, Species, Common_Name, Individual_ID, Phenophase_ID, Phenophase_Description, Observation_Date, Day_of_Year, Phenophase_Status);
```

Any help would be ***really*** appreciated!

Comment: When declaring a `varchar`, you should use a precision -- for example, `varchar(100)`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a length to your varchar fields.  ie: `varchar(10)` for a varchar field of maximum length 10.